# Triple Integral / Volume Evaluation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

**Question:** Find the volume of the solid that lies within both the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$.

The **solution** given to us by our instructor:
$$\int_{0} ^{2\pi}\int _{0} ^{1} \int _{-\sqrt3} ^{\sqrt3} r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

I think this solution is **incorrect** since the top and bottom surfaces in the $z$ direction are clearly not $-\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt3$ and that the radius within the cylinder can't possibly be a constant like 1 if we are starting from the origin. (I could be wrong though).

Can someone please show me how to correctly set up a triple integral to solve this problem or explain to me why the equation above is correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your instinct is spot on. The top and bottom surfaces should be the sphere, not planes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. That's the volume of a cylinder, and therefore it cannot possibly be the right integral. It should be$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt{4-r^2}}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}r\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$